# Mysql select row item as an column

Tags: mysql

I have two tabels '**users**' and '**user_details**';

Table:users

```
---user_id---|-----name-----|
   1         |   John Doe   |
   2         |   Jane Doe   |
   3         | Peter Parker |
```

Table: users_details

```
detail_id--|--user_id--|-----detail-----|---detail_value---|
   1       |   1       |   age          |       28         |
   2       |   1       |   occupation   |       teacher    |
   3       |   1       |   country      |       USA        |
   4       |   2       |   age          |       31         |
   5       |   2       |   occupation   |       designer   |
   6       |   2       |   country      |       Australia  |
   7       |   3       |   age          |       25         |
   8       |   3       |   occupation   |       actor      |
   9       |   3       |   country      |       Canada     |
```

I would like to make a SELECT query , and the output  should be like this :

```
--user_id--|------name----|-----age-----|---occupation---|---country---
   1       |   John Doe   |     28      |     teacher    |    USA
   2       |   Jane Doe   |     31      |     designer   |    Australia
   3       | Peter Parker |     25      |     actor      |    Canada
```

The goal is to select items (age, occupation and country) from the table 'users_details' **as a column**. Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks for Your help.

Answer (score 0):

use conditional aggregation

```
   select u.user_id,u.name,
    max(case when detail='age' then detail_value end) age,
    max(case when detail='occupation' then detail_value end) occupation,
    max(case when detail='country' then detail_value end) country
     from users u join user_details ud on u.user_id=ud.user_id
    group by  u.user_id,u.name
```

Comment: This is actually what I am looking for  .Thank you Zaynul Abadin Tuhin
. I have just tried to filter the results by passing a WHERE clause  for example :  " ...... from users u join user_datails ud on u.user_id=ud.user_id **WHERE  age='28 '** GROUP BY u.user_id, u.name " and as result i get an error  **"Unknown column 'age'"** I ve trierd to fix it but didn't find a way .